# Session não funciona entre functions

Tags: php

```
public function index(){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = 2;
    // Na minha página é impressa o valor "2" 
    echo $_SESSION['user_id']."<br/>";
    $this->view->render("dashboard/dashboard-2");
}

public function teste(){
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['user_id']."<br/>";
   //Notice: Undefined index: user_id
}
```

//Meu HTML

```
       <a href="<?php echo URL ?>dashboard/teste" class="btn btn-primary">TESTE</a>
```

Antes de renderizar a página, eu salvo um `id` na `Session`, no meu caso é `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 2`. Após a página ser renderizada, há um botão de download, no caso um `href` que redireciona para o método `teste()`, porém ao abrir este método, a minha sessão não reconhece o `user_id` e um erro é gerado: `Notice: Undefined index: user_id`.

Há uma coisa estranha também.
Localmente esse código funciona, mas no server (ao ser hospedado) não funciona.

Comment: Em seu PHP.INI o display_errors está configurado como ON?

Answer (score 0):

`<?php` 
`session_start();`

Tente utilizar o session_start na primeira linha do seu arquivo php.